# jQuery variables objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

When I use JavaScript it works.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
```

When I use jQuery to declare it it doesn't.

```
var submitButton = $('#submitButton');
```

I realized when debugging, jQuery is creating a object for the variable.

```
submitButton: Object[span#submitButton.wordButtonD]
```

In JavaScript

```
submitButton: span#submitButton.wordButtonD
```

How do get this to be like javaScript??

Comment: What "it works" means?

Comment: Try this var submitButton = $("#submitButton").attr("id");

Comment: Sorry I meant, it works as in when I use it as an event. Like submitButton.onclick

Comment: @user2537485: why don't you use jquery's `.click()` instead? `$('#submitButton').click(function() { // your handler here });`

Comment: @zerkms: oh, thanks for letting me know :) I am just starting to learn jQuery, I was just confused why the variable set up didn't work. That does look like a better approach though.

Comment: @user2537485: sure. Now you see how useful it's to explain the **original task** not only your attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is: submitButton[0]

Just remember to check the length (greater than 0) because jQuery will return a result even though the element has not been found.

Comment: "because jQuery will return a result" --- it's not a jQuery, but javascript that will do

Comment: @zerkms I would not agree. JavaScript doesn't do anything on its own. It is the jQuery framework that returns a object so that you can chain your calls without worrying for null.

Comment: that's correct, but when you perform `[0]` it's JS that will return `undefined` since it's not possible (?) to override the indexer operator in JS.

Comment: @user2537485: if you work with jquery - why don't you use facilities it provides? It looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Javascript and the result will be as you want. jQuery create its own object to control :). Or please explain more why do you need the result `span#submitButton.wordButtonD` but not `Object[span#submitButton.wordButtonD]`?

Answer (score 0):

statement 1:

```
 var submitButton1 = document.getElementById("submitButton");
```

statement 2:

```
var submitButton2 = $('#submitButton');
```

In above statements, submitButton1 is a DOM object and submitButton2 is a Jquery Object (which already warped your DOM object). Thus, If you want to get Dom object from Jquery object, just do:

```
var submitButton3 = submitButton2[0]
```

OR

```
var submitButton3= submitButton2.get(0)
```

Now, 2 Dom object submitButton1 and submitButton3 are the same.